# How to generate sets of indices where 10% data is left out

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am trying to implement the jackknife method to calculate mean and its corresponding variance for a huge amount of data (a few million data points). Since I have a huge amount of data, if each time only one elements is left out, it is not helping much. I have the code for the case of single element left out:

```
def jackknife(x, func):
    """Jackknife estimate of the estimator func"""
    x = np.asarray(x)
    n = len(x)
    idx = np.arange(n)
    return np.sum(func(x[idx!=i]) for i in range(n))/float(n)

def jackknife_var(x, func):
    """Jackknife estiamte of the variance of the estimator func."""
    x = np.asarray(x)
    n = len(x)
    idx = np.arange(n)
    j_est = jackknife(x, func)
    return j_est, (n-1)/(n + 0.0) * np.sum((func(x[idx!=i]) - j_est)**2.0 for i in range(n))
```

It is quite slow considering the huge data set. Any one has idea how to implement 10% data left-out jackknife method efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using [`sklearn.cross_validation.KFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html)?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
import time

def jackknife(x, func):
    """Jackknife estimate of the estimator func"""
    x = np.asarray(x)
    n = len(x)
    idx = np.arange(n)
    return np.sum(func(x[idx!=i]) for i in range(n))/float(n)


def jackknife_v2(x, func):
    """Jackknife estimate of the estimator func"""
    x = np.asarray(x)
    n = len(x)

    kf = KFold(n, n_folds=10)
    return np.mean([np.sum(func(x[idx])) for idx, _ in kf])

x = np.random.normal(12,3, 100000)

start = time.time()
jack1 = jackknife(x, np.var)
end = time.time()
print('jackknife time elapsed:    {:>10f}'.format(end-start))

start = time.time()
jack2 = jackknife_v2(x, np.var)
end = time.time()
print('jackknife_v2 time elapsed: {:>10f}'.format(end-start))

print(jack1, jack2)

## jackknife time elapsed:     59.567203
## jackknife_v2 time elapsed:   0.005295
## 8.98020789924 8.98019104673
```

Comment: It sounds much faster and meet my requirements. May I ask one more question? What KFold does is to divide the data into n_folds parts, then `[np.sum(func(x[idx])) for idx, _ in kf]` leaves one part out each time, right? My computer has no KFold installed yet. I will ask the computer manager to install it for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Exactly. At each iteration, the `_` corresponds to the indices of the holdout set. So if, instead, you wrote `n_folds=n`, then you would get back your original function that left one element out each time.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps a lot. This tool is for machine learning. I should pick it up soon.